# indoor plant prunning

Tags: avocado

I have 2 avocado plants. i pruned them both and the new growth is growing sideways. I stake one to get it to straight and that plant now has trouble supporting its own weight. I would like to prune them both back to see if the stems will get stronger. they are both in pots inside as we have bad winters. this is just for fun. Do  you think a hard prune indoors at this time is a good idea? or should i wait until spring?

Answer (score 1):

Supporting stems is the same as putting a cast on your arm or leg.  Atrophy.  The movement of the stems/trunks signals the roots to grow supporting roots, larger root systems.  If the branch or stem is immobile it will become very weak.

You are telling me that your avocado plants are indoors?  Do you happen to have a covered porch, patio?  This is where your indoor avocado is able to get more light to make more food and thus be able to survive the winters indoors.  I do this with all my indoor plants; put them out on the covered patio or porch for the summer.  Definitely never receiving full sun.

Pruning a baby avocado tree is not a good idea.  Every single leaf of that plant is oh so necessary to provide food for that plant.  You cut those factories off and the plant languishes.

I would, however, cut the apical tip off your plant.  That has the MOST energy of the entire plant.  Cut that off and that energy is diverted down the stem to the rest of the plant.  Very good thing.

Send a picture, if you are able.  I'd like to see the pot, the soil and hoping that the soil is sterilized potting soil, how you water, when you know your plant needs more water, the color of the leaves...heck, have you fertilized?  Less is Best, More is Death and None is Dumb...my own little ditty.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good idea if you want them bushy instead of one stem. Just remember when you cut a stem it makes two branches. If you can, prune it down to a node that faces the direction you want it to go.